# Извлечь структурированные данные

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется строка вида

```
email=email@ya.ru&login=Vasua&uid=54248
```

Как из неё автоматически заполнить форму

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email">E-mail<Br>
  <input type="text" name="login">Login<Br>
  <input type="text" name="uid">UID</p>
  <p><input type="submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090551/parse-query-string-in-javascript

Comment: @splash58, не стоит давать только ссылки на ответ. Плюс - оформляйте как ответ, комментарий нельзя принять.

Comment: это не ответ, это ссылка на похожий вопрос на аyглийском SO. Поскольку на английском, то называть дубликатом неправильно наверное, а переписывать как ответ - еще глупее :)

Comment: @splash58, вот именно что нужно - пусть данное решение видят все, кто ещё не знаком с английским. Просто оставить в конце ссылку на ответ - что-то типа копирайта.

Comment: тогда, наверное, правильнее делать это, как общий ответ. Хорошая работа для модераторов :)). я не знаю, позволяет ли мне рейтинг, но всё-равно не умею

Comment: @splash58, хах, как будто это работа только модераторов - отвечать и переводить.

Comment: @Other вам не кажется, что мы не очень осмысленную беседу ведем :) по крайней мере, тут ей не очень место. Если вы считаете, что по ссылке ответ на вопрос, давно бы написали. А я тут выяснилось , гол пропустил :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38979/discussion-between-other-and-splash58).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let str = `email=email@ya.ru&login=Vasua&uid=54248`;

function parseQuery(query = '') {
  let tmp = {};

  String(query).trim().split('&').forEach(e => tmp[decodeURIComponent(e.split('=')[0])] = decodeURIComponent(e.split('=')[1]));
  return tmp;
}

let obj = parseQuery(str); // Декодируем строку запроса в объект

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { // Дожидаемся загрузки DOM, иначе элементов не найдёшь
  Object.keys(obj).forEach(e => { // Перебираем все ключи, т.е. name
    let el = null;

    if ((el = document.querySelector(`[name=${e}]`)) !== null) { // Ищем элемент по name
      el.value = obj[e]; // Если нашли, то вставляем значение
    } else {
      console.info(`Element '[name=${e}]' not found!`);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="email">E-mail
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="login">Login
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="uid">UID
  <p>
    <input type="submit">
  </p>
</form>
```